# exporting an file as fbx fails

Tags: export, unity

I am trying to export as fbx and getting the following error:
[image]

I think it might be because the project has some missing files that I'm not able to delete. I tried to unlink or clear but it doesn't work and I have no meshes using them.
.

Comment: same here! I also read a post talking about UVMaps and renaming them to solve the problem https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?392170-Error-when-trying-to-export-to-fbx

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, export as obj, reload start up file, import the obj then export as fbx.

Comment: can you add more to this answer? answers in general should be more then one line.

Comment: Worked for me, thank you!  Wish I knew "why" it fixes it, but happy to report that works!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is years ago, but I found a solution where one of my bones was scaled to 0. I reset the scale and it exported fine

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a couple years old, but people may be experiencing this problem in the future. Here are couple of things you can try to avoid this error.

- This may happen if you smart UV unwrap an object. You may have to manually do the uv map or use a cube, cylinder and/or sphere projection.
- Double check the materials on objects, you may be experiencing a 'list index out of range'. This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/5xkupy/help_exporting_fbx_error_looking_for_help/) explains it well.
- Objects with invalid location and extremely high or low scales also can throw errors.
- If you aren't concerned about materials on the object, trying exporting as an obj, then reimport into blender and export once again as a fbx.

Hope this helps. It may be a bit of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the option of exporting as a obj but lost the animations, I also renamed all my UVMaps and still it did not work. I had a lot of animations for my character and when i removed some of these it seemed to work ok, so if the other options fail, try that.